# Start a script in background when django project start

Tags: python, django

I have a script which fetches data from some API and add the data to mongodb. The data is necessary for my django project. Also the script is separate from project.
The django project is for a single account only. As the number of account goes up, I have to setup individual project for each account. (Replica of each other with different Credentials. Cannot have multiple on same project.)

I thought of cron jobs but it will be very confusing to seperate jobs for a number of accounts.

I also searched about `subprocess.Popen` which i think will serve the purpose of running a script in background. i.e. when project server is run the python script is started as a background process.

My script is like:

```
func1():
    while True:
        # do something
        sleep(30)

func2():
    while True:
        # do something
        sleep(150)

func3():
    while True:
        # do something
        sleep(900)

func4():
    while True:
        # do something
        sleep(7200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p3 = Process(target = func3)
    p4 = Process(target = func4)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How much will it affect the system resources (Memory and CPU)? Is it okay to run such kind of script in background process continuously?
2. Is there any other alternative where the scripts starts by itself when the project is run?

Note:  Currently I am using apache with mod_wsgi to run my project.

Comment: For 2, how about Celery beat? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid never ending processes.
What if there is a memory leak in one of those jobs?

As @user1157751 mentioned in a comment, celery beat seems the way to go for this. Have a look to the documentation, also celery flower provides you with a management panel so you can monitor your tasks.

[Celery website](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/)